# Generate PDF using xelatex engine

Tags: xepersian, msc

I want to write UML code using `msc` package.
So I write the code like below:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: clean1
% arara: clean: { files: [ Commands.aux , .main.ptd , TP.aux] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}

%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{Example}
\declinst{usr}{User}{}
\declinst{m1}{Machine 1}{control}
\declinst{m2}{Machine 2}{drill}
\declinst{m3}{Machine 3}{test}
\mess{startm1}{usr}{m1}
\nextlevel
\mess{startm2}{m1}{m2}
\nextlevel
\mess{continue}{m2}{m3}
\mess{log}{m1}{envleft}
\nextlevel
\mess{output}{m3}{usr}[2]
\nextlevel
\mess{free}{m1}{usr}
\nextlevel
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

It works fine and generate pdf by running with `XeLatex` engine.
But when I active the package `xepersian`, then it does not work and no pdf.
What can I do?

---

When I run with xepersian package I do not get error but I can not open pdf
[image]

---

I upload the log file in the link below:

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/638354/aa.log

http://etc.zarup.com/100025-download-aa.log.html

Comment: Going against the guidelines of `expl3` programming, the author of XePersian used a private `fontspec` function in the code for `\settextfont`. The private function is `\__fontspec_pass_args:nnn` which has been removed in the last version of `fontspec`: no other package should have relied on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, fixing the code at the document level is not possible, because the faulty macros are used in the package itself.

Comment: But all of my document works fine with `xepersian`. why? for example this code 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
سلام
\end{document}

Comment: Apparently you haven't updated your TeX system yet. Can you show the error message you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. But pdf does not generate or it generates but I can not open it

Comment: Show the log-file.

Comment: How can I attach log file?

I can not do this

Comment: I upload it to free upload site!

Comment: I don't intend to use a service which ask me for my email.

Comment: I change it!!!!  You should use red button.

دانلود فایل is translate of "Download file" in my mother tongue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the `msc` environment in a `latin` one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Al Bayan}

\begin{document}

\begin{latin}
\begin{msc}{Example}
\declinst{usr}{User}{}
\declinst{m1}{Machine 1}{control}
\declinst{m2}{Machine 2}{drill}
\declinst{m3}{Machine 3}{test}
\mess{startm1}{usr}{m1}
\nextlevel
\mess{startm2}{m1}{m2}
\nextlevel
\mess{continue}{m2}{m3}
\mess{log}{m1}{envleft}
\nextlevel
\mess{output}{m3}{usr}[2]
\nextlevel
\mess{free}{m1}{usr}
\nextlevel
\end{msc}
\end{latin}

سلام

\end{document}
```

Beware that with the most recent updates to `fontspec` the package `xepersian` doesn't work. The cause is its author going against `expl3` programming guidelines and using a private `fontspec` function, now removed.

I'm referring to `xepersian` version 17.2 (2017/01/16) and `fontspec` version 2.5d (2017/01/24).

[image]

Comment: Yes. It works fine. 

Thank you. But it takes too time to run. Why?